# Is there a limit for the number of attachments on a list item?

Tags: list, attachments

I have a list that users are attaching files too and I was wondering if there is a limit of the number of attachments to a list item? Or a a limit of the number of attachments to a list in total?

Comment: Is there any file size limit ?

Comment: The maximum size for files attached to list items is 250 MB as per the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#:~:text=The%20maximum%20size%20for%20files%20attached%20to%20list%20items%20is%20250%20MB.) on Microsoft site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b05468ff-5916-4c6b-b159-e58109f9dd43/sharepoint-list-item-attachment-limitation) thread:

> There is **no** maximum limit specified for the number of attachments that
>   you can add to a SharePoint list item. But if you have a mobile view,
>   the number of attachments displayed is limited to 3.